# Making a request to the Google Apps Script API through postman

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, postman, http-status-code-403, google-apps-script-api

I am attempting to remotely execute a google apps script function using the apps script api through a postman request.

I first get credentials from the [Google API Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

Then they are inputted into postman as OAuth2 credentials, and inputted in the headers like this:
[image]

Then the appropriate link is requested:
[image]

Then the body prepared:
[image]

And then the response after making the request:
[image]

Postman is returning an error 403, which, according to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run)

indicates that "the Cloud Platform project used to authorize the request is not the same as the one used by the script." An error 403 is an authorization error and can mean many things, but let's assume that the error is what google proclaims it to be.

I have full control over the GCP project utilized by my script, but I'm not aware of where to find the project that was used to authorize the request.

Where might I gain access to this GCP project so I can assign my script to this project, thereby eliminating the 403 error?

Thanks!

Comment: 403 means authorization error which can mean just about anything.

Comment: Sure: but according to the documentation it is likely what is specified. Let's just assume it is what Google proclaims it to be: How do I access this GCP project? I have updated a question to account for this Caveat.

Comment: Show your code, the steps that you are using to authorize and the exact error message. Otherwise, I need to put new batteries in my crystal ball.

Comment: Were those edits sufficient to get your crystal ball working?

Comment: In the OAuth Playground. Click on the gear icon (top right). What did you enter under "Use your own OAuth credentials"? Make sure that the Client ID is for the same project that your Apps Script project is accessing.

Comment: I just entered the client secret and ID authorized from the GCP project associated with the script- No more 403! Although there is a 404 now, but that should be easier to solve.

Comment: Also this may have solved the issue, I do not know the detailed reasons why. Can you point me to some resources that I can read up on so I will intuitively understand the issue?

Comment: Start here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: I will post an answer. Close this question. If you need more help, create a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use OAuth Access Tokens from the OAuth Playground with Apps Script, you need to specify the correct Client ID and Client Secret from the same project.

In the OAuth Playground. Click on the gear icon (top right). Select "Use your own OAuth credentials". Then enter the Client ID and Secret ID created in the same project as Apps Script.

Answer (score 1):

To query a Google URL using a valid Access token with Postman you can log the access token from apps script and use it after.

In your apps script after validating scope, i.e. running a first time the script, log the token :

```
function logToken(){
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken());
}
```

Then in Postman query the Google URL by setting in the header the access token :

"Authorization": "Bearer THE_ACCESS_TOKEN"

**Security warning** : for security reason I have to tell you that an access token is valid 1 hour so technically if you grant full drive scope to your app with this access token we can browse all your Drive.